# Would asking a question about medical school admissions, compared to STEM PhD admissions, and hiring practices, be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Would asking a question about medical school admissions, compared to STEM PhD admissions, and hiring practices, be on-topic here?

I have thought of either posting it here, or on Academia or Economics.

Economics I'd rather avoid, since it seems like a very low-activity site.

Comment: Thanks, downvoter 

Comment: Admissions is definitely off-topic here, hiring practices may be on-topic depending on what exactly you mean by that. (Not the downvoter, by the way.)

Comment: And also not your down-voter, but keep in mind that [votes in Meta work differently](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). They indicate agreement or disagreement, not just quality of the question.

Comment: @DavidK ah, I see.  Ok, cool.  I'll post at Academia then :) I upvoted your comments, as well as Masked Man's comments :)

Comment: @D.Hutchinson I moved my comment to an answer, since that's really what it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I don't believe your topic would be a good fit for The Workplace.**

If your question is on-topic anywhere, it would probably be at [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). There they can at least talk about hiring practices within academia, whereas we can't really talk about admissions here. Of course, whether it's on-topic there or not depends on the exact nature of your question, so be sure to look over their [on-topic definitions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).